# Exponential growth/reduction of Laser Intensity question?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Hi i have a pretty simple question but I am not quite sure on how to solve/approach it.

THe question: "The Intensity of a laserbeam declines with the penetrationdepth into matter exponentially. At 6mm depth the intensity has been reduced to 10% of the original value.

Formulate the Intensityreduction formula."

I am not quite sure on how to solve this and any hints/helpful nudges would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, write

$$I(z)=I(0) e^{-a z}$$

We seek $a$.  We get this knowing that

$$I(6) = I(0) e^{-6 a} = 0.1 I(0)$$

which means that

$$e^{-6 a}=0.1 \implies 6 a=-\ln{0.1} = \ln{10} \implies a = \frac16 \ln{10}$$

Therefore

$$I(z) = I(0) e^{-(1/6) \ln{10} z} = I(0) 10^{-z/6}$$

Comment: Thank you, may i ask 2 questions:
1) Where is the Formula I(z) = I(0)e^-az taken from?
2) Where does the 0.1*I*(0) come from?

Comment: @Orbital: 1) standard exponential behavior; in this context, it is sometimes called Beer's law.  2) Really?

Comment: 1) Thanks! Will do some reading on this now.
2) Yeah really =/ Sorry im having somewhat of a brainlag right now

Comment: @Orbital: It is your problem statement!  I must ask you to contribute some brain cells to this endeavor.

Comment: Oh god.. im so ashamed right now for myself.... seriously my face couldnt be any redder if you spanked me, thank you so much :)